# Fix reduce in console

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I used to combine two observables into one, and then get the only unique values, so after:

```
const latest = combineLatest(...queryResults, (...arrays) => arrays.reduce((
  acc: any,
  array: any
) => [...acc, ...array], []));
```

I have an array with:

```
0: {id: "id1", categories: Array(1), value: "Stadium"}
1: {id: "id2", categories: Array(2), value: "ball"}
2: {id: "id3", categories: Array(2), value: "ball"}
3: {id: "id4", categories: Array(1), value: "Woman"}
4: {id: "id5", categories: Array(2), value: "head"}
```

and after

```
return latest.pipe(
  map(words => {
    return words.reduce((unique, o) => {
      if (!unique.some(obj => obj.id === o.id)) {
        unique.push(o);
      }
      return unique;
    }, []);
  })
);
```

the result is:

```
0: {id: "id1", categories: Array(1), value: "Stadium"}
1: {id: "id2", categories: Array(2), value: "ball"}
2: {id: "id4", categories: Array(1), value: "Woman"}
3: {id: "id5", categories: Array(2), value: "head"}
```

and it's ok. It's working fine. My question is related to console error:

```
ERROR in src/app/core/services/learning.service.ts(137,22): error TS2339: Property 'reduce' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Line 137 -> return words.reduce((unique, o) => { ...

How to fix it?

Comment: why it works , from your code it seems you are not picking the right item coming from combinelatest

Comment: Please look at this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eaevq9

'words' is not an array, so that's why the error message is visible, but why it works? Good question ;) and how to fix that? Maybe second reduce is not needed, but how to code this better to get only unique values?

Comment: ok, it was typescript error only. I added a type here (map((words: Word[]) => { ....) and it's working

Comment: if you find the answer helps pls mark it up or accept as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

It is bascially an array operation, but with rxjs it can be simplified with `distinctUntilKeyChange`, but before apply that you will have merge the observable result array first, please see below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { of, combineLatest } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map,toArray,switchMap,tap,distinctUntilKeyChanged  } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  observables = []

  ob1 = of([
    {id: "id1", categories: Array(1), value: "Stadium"},
    {id: "id2", categories: Array(2), value: "ball"}
  ])

  ob2 = of([
    {id: "id2", categories: Array(2), value: "ball"},
    {id: "id4", categories: Array(1), value: "Woman"},
    {id: "id5", categories: Array(2), value: "head"}
  ])

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.observables.push(this.ob1);
    this.observables.push(this.ob2);

    const latest = combineLatest(...this.observables).pipe(switchMap((arr)=>{
return arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>acc.concat(curr),[])
    }));

const result = latest.pipe(
     distinctUntilKeyChanged("id"),toArray()
    );

    result.subscribe(words => {
      console.warn(words);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: You tested it? I have 'Property 'concat' does not exist on type '{}'.'

Comment: Ya I did. That’s not a run time error I believe. It is a typescript error. Just need to fix the typing. If u see correct result in  console means it works